# ssh config: how to cascade config

Tags: ssh

Say I have this ssh config file:

```
host server1
  user myUser1
  hostname 192.168.0.1
host server2
  user myUser
  hostname 192.168.0.2
host 192.168.0.*
  # global config here (such as proxycommand, etc)
```

How can I make it so that the global config is applied to server1 & server2 ?

Edit:

I don't want to solve this using patterns, I want the last 'host' entry to check for previous hostnames. I think there's an option to do that, but I couldn't find it on the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Host` keyword matches against the target host; the host given on the command line.
Thus, when using the following file, `ssh test-host` will connect to `192.168.0.1` with the *current username* (i.e: ignoring the IP-specific config) - because `test-host` doesn't match `192.168.0.1`.

```
Host test-host
    Hostname 192.168.0.1

Host 192.168.0.1
    User test-user
```

To make the above work as expected, you must set `CanonicalizeHostname=yes` in your configuration file. This can be placed in the global section (at the top), or on a per-host basis, for example:

```
Host test-host
    Hostname 192.168.0.1
    CanonicalizeHostname yes

Host 192.168.0.1
    User test-user
```

This would cause the `test-host` to be re-written `192.168.0.1`.

Note that `ProxyCommand` has special semantics:

> `CanonicalizeHostname`
>
> Controls whether explicit hostname canonicalization is performed.  The default, `no`, is not to perform any name rewriting and let the system resolver handle all hostname lookups.  If set to `yes` then, **for connections that do not use a `ProxyCommand`**, `ssh(1)` will attempt to canonicalize the hostname specified on the command line using the `CanonicalDomains` suffixes and `CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs` rules.  **If `CanonicalizeHostname` is set to `always`, then canonicalization is applied to proxied connections too.**
>
> If this option is enabled, then the configuration files are processed again using the new target name to pick up any new configuration in matching `Host` and `Match` stanzas.

---

Alternatives to achieve the behaviour you're after, are below:

#### A

```
host server1
  user myUser1
  hostname 192.168.0.1

host server2
  user myUser
  hostname 192.168.0.2

host server1 server2
  # global config here (such as proxycommand, etc)
```

#### B

```
host 192.168.0.1
  user myUser1

host 192.168.0.2
  user myUser

host 192.168.0.*
  # global config here (such as proxycommand, etc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew these 2 options were a possibility, but I was aware (but lost my config file) of a third option, wherein I could put any name in the host parameter, and still have the last global config be called anyway (if it matched the IP address). I am sure it worked, I just don't remember what parameter I used.

Comment: I think it may have to do with 'match' or 'CanonicalizeHostname' or something like that, to make it parse the file multiple times, but I can't find the right set of options.

Comment: quite right too! `CanonicalizeHostname` does what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

As you have alredy shown, you can add a `Host *` or even `Host server*` stanza to your config file which will apply to all hosts which match the (limited) regex.  E.g.

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand ...
```

There is also the `?` pattern which matches a single character, as in:

```
Host server?
  ...
```

You can also apply to multiple hosts, separated by spaces, as in:

```
Host crypto cryptonomicon crypto.example.com
  HostName crypto.example.com
  HostKeyAlias crypto
  User me
```

FWIW, all of this is clearly defined in the [`ssh_config` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) - look for the section titled "Patterns"

Comment: I know about partterns, but it is not what I'm looking for. I think there's an option to make the 'host' parameter check for previous hostnames, but I don't remember what it is and couldn't find it on the documentation (see OP edit).